# Is it possible to provide a view-only remote access for non-administrative user in win 2008 r2?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server.
It has a user named "buildit".

How can i provide a view-only Remote Desktop kinda access to "buildit" user?

Please do note that i wont have a active session open for buildit.
So, i think VNC sessions are ruled out

Is there any other options??

Comment: [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/nl/index.aspx) can do that.

Comment: @DavidPostill, Teamviewer will not connect when RDP session is closed...